# error while building Glibc-2.11.1 for Linux From Scratch

Tags: c, linux, unix, gcc, glibc

I am trying to configure glibc-2.11.1 using gcc-4.6.1 for kernel 3.16. I am following steps given at http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Configuring-and-compiling.html when i am doing make after compiling some file it is giving

```
make -r PARALLELMFLAGS="" CVSOPTS="" -C ../glibc-2.11.1 objdir=`pwd` all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/amar/Desktop/glib1/glibc-2.11.1'
make  subdir=csu -C csu ..=../ subdir_lib
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/amar/Desktop/glib1/glibc-2.11.1/csu'
gcc /home/amar/Desktop/glib1/gnu/csu/crti.S -c  -I../include -I/home/amar/Desktop/glib1/gnu/csu -I/home/amar/Desktop/glib1/gnu -I../sysdeps/i386/elf -I../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/i686 -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/i686 -I../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386 -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386 -I../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux -I../nptl/sysdeps/pthread -I../sysdeps/pthread -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux -I../sysdeps/gnu -I../sysdeps/unix/common -I../sysdeps/unix/mman -I../sysdeps/unix/inet -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/i386 -I../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv -I../sysdeps/unix/i386 -I../nptl/sysdeps/unix -I../sysdeps/unix -I../sysdeps/posix -I../sysdeps/i386/i686/fpu -I../nptl/sysdeps/i386/i686 -I../sysdeps/i386/i686 -I../sysdeps/i386/i486 -I../nptl/sysdeps/i386/i486 -I../sysdeps/i386/fpu -I../nptl/sysdeps/i386 -I../sysdeps/i386 -I../sysdeps/wordsize-32 -I../sysdeps/ieee754/ldbl-96 -I../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64 -I../sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32 -I../sysdeps/ieee754 -I../sysdeps/generic/elf -I../sysdeps/generic -I../nptl  -I.. -I../libio -I.  -D_LIBC_REENTRANT -include ../include/libc-symbols.h       -DHAVE_INITFINI -DASSEMBLER  -I/home/amar/Desktop/glib1/gnu/csu/. -DGAS_SYNTAX -g -Wa,--noexecstack   -g0  -o /home/amar/Desktop/glib1/gnu/csu/crti.o
/tmp/ccEB9vct.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccEB9vct.s: Error: open CFI at the end of file; missing .cfi_endproc directive
/tmp/ccEB9vct.s: Error: open CFI at the end of file; missing .cfi_endproc directive
make[2]: *** [/home/amar/Desktop/glib1/gnu/csu/crti.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/amar/Desktop/glib1/glibc-2.11.1/csu'
make[1]: *** [csu/subdir_lib] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/amar/Desktop/glib1/glibc-2.11.1'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Why is it so ? How I can rectify this error? Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Sathish how is that link related to this problem? I'm pretty sure that if installing more memory will help assemble `crti.S` then he'd have had bigger problems before getting this far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is it so ?

The file `crti.S` that is failing to build is generated by compiling `csu/initfini.c`, and then splitting the resulting `initfini.s` on "magic markers".

Unfortunately, this splitting is extremely dependent on the version of `gcc` that is used to generate `initfini.s`, and doesn't always work.

This entire mechanism has been eliminated in Feb 2012.

Your options are:

- build a newer version of glibc (current is 2.19), or
- build using older version of GCC (Google search shows many instances of gcc-4.6 causing this problem).